# Empty Threadcontext braces scenario handling in log4j2

Tags: java, stack, log4j2, threadcontext

I am trying to migrate to log4j2. 
In RollingFile Appender I am adding as below:

```
<PatternLayout>
    <pattern>[%d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:SSS z}] %-18.18t %-35.35c{1} %-5p (%F:%L) %m \t %x %n</pattern>
</PatternLayout>
```

We know that %x is for printing stack elements to end of the every logger statement.

Now if my stack is empty initially, it is giving me the empty braces as below.

```
[01/10/17 12:17:37:116 IST] main               Example2                            WARN  (Example2.java:52) 10 is the number     []
```

[01/10/17 12:17:37:116 IST] main               Example2                            WARN  (Example2.java:52) 10 is the number     []

So how do I handle this empty stack scenario ?

Comment: I want the logger without braces as below.


        
`[01/10/17 12:17:37:116 IST] main               Example2                            WARN  (Example2.java:52) 10 is the number`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout)'s `notEmpty{pattern}` pattern converter:

This outputs the result of evaluating the pattern if and only if all variables in the pattern are not empty.

For example:

```
%notEmpty{[%x]}
```

Aliases: variablesNotEmpty{pattern}, 
varsNotEmpty{pattern}, 
notEmpty{pattern}

Comment: This will not work. Its taking `%notEmpty{[%x]}` as **%n** and takes the logger to next line.

Comment: What version are you using? This feature is fairly recent. Have you tried `varsNotEmpty`?

Comment: Version 2.7? Or something older?

Comment: Now the ouput logger is `[01/11/17 12:22:59:693 IST] main               Example2                            DEBUG (Example2.java:56) 10 is the number   
otEmpty`

Comment: Can't migrate to v2.7 as can't go beyond Java 6. Hence I am using log4j v2.3

Comment: Ouch. %notEmpty doesn't exist in 2.3. You can backport as a custom plugin. Just take the source & compile in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use %equals{pattern}{test}{substitution} from https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

For example -

%equals{%x}{[]}{}

This will replace [] with empty string.
Worked for me.